ASP.NET Core 8 MVC + Docker not running
I created images for my ASP.NET Core 8 MVC project, but when I try to access it locally, it is not working showing an error "This site can't be reached".
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0

WORKDIR /WebApplication

COPY . .

RUN dotnet build

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["dotnet", "watch", "run"]

I run the docker run command with parameters
docker run -p 8080:80 userproject:1

Can you tell me what the issue is?
My container logs are as follow
dotnet watch ⌚ Polling file watcher is enabled
dotnet watch  Hot reload enabled. For a list of supported edits, see https://aka.ms/dotnet/hot-reload.
   Press "Ctrl + R" to restart.
dotnet watch  Building...
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  WebApplication1 -> /WebApplication/bin/Debug/net8.0/WebApplication1.dll
dotnet watch  Started
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[15]
      Overriding HTTP_PORTS '8080' and HTTPS_PORTS ''. Binding to values defined by URLS instead 'http://0.0.0.0:80'.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:80
dotnet watch  Unable to launch the browser. Navigate to http://0.0.0.0:80
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /WebApplication
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.


Your app might be running on HTTPS. Can you try adding ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://*:8443 in Dockerfile and try docker run -p 8443:8443 userproject:1 to see if you can access the application on https://localhost:8443.

First of all your method of running dotnet projects in a docker container seems wrong for multiple reasons. I mean the dotnet watch run command is used for development only where it needs to watch file changes and act thereof.
And you there’s no point of running dotnet build as you don’t actually using the build artifacts in this dockerfile.
Please adjust your Dockerfile as follows:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/WebApplication/WebApplication.csproj", "src/WebApplication/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/WebApplication/WebApplication.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/WebApplication"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication.dll"]

Assuming you have your project in src directory inside your solution. If not just remove the src/ prefix as follows:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication/WebApplication.csproj", "WebApplication/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication/WebApplication.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication.dll"]


is it necessary to publish app before creating image?
